# Unity - Multiple interface registration with a factory method to return same implementation

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

Consider I have the following types:

```cs
public interface IBaseInterface { }

public interface IInheritedInterface : IBaseInterface { }

public class MyClass : IInheritedInterface { }

//------------------------------------------------------------

public interface ISomeInterface { }

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface {
  private readonly IBaseInterface _myInterface;

  public SomeClass(IBaseInterface myInterface) {
    _myInterface = myInterface;
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

public interface ISomeOtherInterface { }

public class SomeOtherClass : ISomeOtherInterface {
  private readonly IInheritedInterface _myInterface;

  public SomeOtherClass(IInheritedInterface myInterface) {
    _myInterface = myInterface;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, what I am trying to achieve and wonder how could be done, if possible, is that whenever I construct either `SomeClass` or `SomeOtherClass` is to always get the same instance of `MyClass`. This example explains what I want:

```cs
var someClass = _container.Resolve<SomeClass>();
var someOtherClass = _container.Resolve<SomeOtherClass>();
// At this point, The following assert should pass
Assert.AreSame(someClass._myInterface, someOtherClass._myInterface)
```

Also note that `MyClass` needs to register using a factory method for other reasons. I have tried the following:

```cs
_container.RegisterType<IBaseInterface, MyClass>(
    perRequestLifetime, 
    new InjectionFactory((c) => 
        { return FactoryMethod(c); }));
```

This will resolve `SomeClass` but will throw when trying to resolve `SomeOtherClass` since the container doesn't know how to construct `IInheritedInterface`.

I have also tried this:

```cs
_container.RegisterType<IBaseInterface, MyClass(
    perRequestLifetime,
    new InjectionFactory((c) => {
        MyClass myClass;
        // Construct object some how...
        return myClass;
    }));

_container.RegisterType<IInheritedInterface, MyClass(
    perRequestLifetime,
    new InjectionFactory((c) => {
        return c.Resolve<IBaseInterface>() as MyClass;
    }));
```

However, for some reason when I call `Resolve()` on both `SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` they both end up calling the factory of `IInheritedInterface` causing an endless loop! I then removed IBaseInterface registration and now resolving `SomeClass` throws.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```csh
container.RegisterType<IBaseInterface, MyClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(ctr => new MyClass()));
container.RegisterType<IInheritedInterface, MyClass>();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's funny how a solution could be very simple but you never think about it. Cheers.